# I have an error with the file (web.xml) in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I have an error and I don´t know resolve it.
The question is:
when I make something in my java class and after I press save, I have go the file web.xml for save it without next code:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>services</param-name>
      <param-value/>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SystemServiceServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/spi/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

this code I have comment it and afterwards it save
If I don´t make that then I come out the next message error:

```
    25-oct-2012 9:29:01 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ADVERTENCIA: EXCEPTION 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.IsolatedAppClassLoader.loadClass(IsolatedAppClassLoader.java:176)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:91)
    at org.mortbay.util.Loader.loadClass(Loader.java:71)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:73)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:191)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restart(DevAppServerImpl.java:265)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher$AppEngineServletContainer.refresh(AppEngineLauncher.java:51)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.onRestartServer(DevMode.java:349)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteUI.restartWebServer(RemoteUI.java:166)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.processRestartServer(DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.java:94)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.execute(DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.java:59)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.processClientRequest(MessageTransport.java:362)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.processMessage(MessageTransport.java:404)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.access$400(MessageTransport.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport$3.run(MessageTransport.java:322)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
25-oct-2012 9:29:01 com.google.appengine.tools.development.ApiProxyLocalImpl log
GRAVE: javax.servlet.ServletContext log: unavailable
javax.servlet.UnavailableException: com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.doStart(Holder.java:79)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:242)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:191)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restart(DevAppServerImpl.java:265)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher$AppEngineServletContainer.refresh(AppEngineLauncher.java:51)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.onRestartServer(DevMode.java:349)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteUI.restartWebServer(RemoteUI.java:166)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.processRestartServer(DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.java:94)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.execute(DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.java:59)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.processClientRequest(MessageTransport.java:362)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.processMessage(MessageTransport.java:404)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.access$400(MessageTransport.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport$3.run(MessageTransport.java:322)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

25-oct-2012 9:29:01 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ADVERTENCIA: failed SystemServiceServlet: java.lang.NullPointerException
25-oct-2012 9:29:01 com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.JettyLogger warn
ADVERTENCIA: Failed startup of context com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext@8d5bff{/,C:\Alberto\workspace\uned\RepresentacionAfc\war}
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.Class.isAssignableFrom(Native Method)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.doStart(ServletHolder.java:256)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:685)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:140)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1250)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:517)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:467)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService.startContainer(JettyContainerService.java:191)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.AbstractContainerService.startup(AbstractContainerService.java:239)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restart(DevAppServerImpl.java:265)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.development.gwt.AppEngineLauncher$AppEngineServletContainer.refresh(AppEngineLauncher.java:51)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.onRestartServer(DevMode.java:349)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.RemoteUI.restartWebServer(RemoteUI.java:166)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.processRestartServer(DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.java:94)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.execute(DevModeServiceRequestProcessor.java:59)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.processClientRequest(MessageTransport.java:362)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.processMessage(MessageTransport.java:404)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport.access$400(MessageTransport.java:44)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.remoteui.MessageTransport$3.run(MessageTransport.java:322)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Does anybody know the reason?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you imported the *.jar file, which has "com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet" implemented?

Answer (score 0):

The exception says that your class:

```
<servlet-class>com.google.api.server.spi.SystemServiceServlet</servlet-class>
```

cannot be found. Try to make sure that you've imported the corresponding .jar file at the compiled and other runtime

Answer (score 0):

Thank for answer.

I have been looking and I have all *.jar file imported

I´ve implemented the methods synchronous that I need for my application, this methods are declares in the web.xml file

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>afcService</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.afc.server.AfcServiceImpl</servlet-class>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>afcService</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/representacionafc/afcService</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

If I don´t put the code above then the application doesn´t have any error, but If I uncomment the code above then I have problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and it took me a while to figure it out.

At first I recognized that I definitely need SystemServiceServlet to send mails for excample

Than I found out that this is no google or eclipse problem as it worked fine for me if I created a brand new GEA project over the eclipse wizard.

I think it was a maven gwt-maven-plugin version 2.5.0-rc1 problem as this version of the plugin did not add the GAE builder into the builder section of eclipse.

I migrated to version 2.5.0-rc2 closed the project in eclipse clean all the m2e stuff (.settings, the bin folder and so on). Afterwards I reimported the project and enabled GAE and every thing worked again.

Never the less it is really strange.